# detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Im using x-code 3.2.4 and I'm using the ios4.1 sdk.

I'm getting the following error when I try to call "ExtAudioFileOpenURL" from the audio toolbox.

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol
>   in system libraries that is not
>   present on the iPhone:
>   _Unwind_Resume called from function _ZN15ID3ParserHandleC2EPvPFlS0_mmmPS0_PmE
>   in image AudioToolbox.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
db.

**EDIT**

In addition when running on a 4.1 device I get this error "error: 805297555"

What the hell?

The exact line of code causing the problem is this.

```
// Open an audio file and associate it with the extended audio file object.
         OSStatus result= ExtAudioFileOpenURL (sourceURLArray[audioFile], &audioFileObject);
```

It's straight out of a sample code project. That sample code project runs fine.

I don't understand why if I start a new project with the same code I get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do in the end was completely uninstall the developer tools from my machine.
Then download the latest versions of xcode & ios SDK.

Everything works ok now.

Sadly I still don't exactly know what the problem was but at least things are running.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `ExtAudioFileOpenURL` is an unsupported API on the iPhone. `ExtAudioFileOpenURL` probably makes use of some exception handling API that is not available on the iPhone, which is why you are seing this sympton of the underlying error.

Comment: hm... maybe some weird non-standard linker setting?

Comment: can you suggest a route for investigation?