# App Crashing while populating data in the database

Tags: ios4, ipad

My app is crashing while populating data in the database with this error message :

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries
that is not present on the iPhone:usleep$UNIX2003 called
from function -[FMDatabase executeQuery:arguments:]
in image My Project.
If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary
within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.
```

Answer (score 0):

usleep$UNIX2003 is not supported on the iphone

Similar issue - [detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185020/detected-an-attempt-to-call-a-symbol-in-system-libraries-that-is-not-present-on-t)

> What I had to do in the end was
>   completely uninstall the developer
>   tools from my machine. Then download
>   the latest versions of xcode & ios
>   SDK.
>
> Everything works ok now.
>
> Sadly I still don't exactly know what
>   the problem was but at least things
>   are running.